# Perl what does Taint means in general

Tags: perl

I read a lot about `Taint` in Perl variables, mode etc, for example from the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/perl594delta.html#%24AUTOLOAD-can-now-be-tainted):

> `$AUTOLOAD` can now be tainted
>
> If you call a subroutine by a tainted name, and if it defers to an `AUTOLOAD` function, then `$AUTOLOAD` will be (correctly) tainted.

While the definition of the word taint from google is:

> Definitions of taint
>
> *verb*
>
> 1. contaminate or pollute (something).
>      "the air was tainted by fumes from the cars"
>      synonyms: contaminate, pollute, adulterate, infect, blight, spoil, soil, ruin, destroy, befoul
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. a trace of a bad or undesirable quality or substance.
>      "the taint of corruption that adhered to the regime"
>      synonyms: trace, touch, suggestion, hint, tinge, stain, blot, blemish, stigma, black mark, discredit, dishonor, disgrace, shame

So what does `Taint` mean in general in Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell: Any data coming from outside and thus are not in control of the program get flagged as tainted. Sensitive operations like system or exec refuse to work on these tainted data, that is you need to untaint the data by verifying their content. Used correctly this prevents command injections and similar problems.

Comment: does that means I can manually flag/unflag any variable as tainted. how to flag it and how to check if it is flaged?

Comment: @daliaessam for checking if tainted see `tainted()` in [`Sclar::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.39/lib/Scalar/Util.pm) There is also [`Taint::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/~avar/Taint-Util-0.08/Util.pm) for taint manipulation.

Comment: Usually you untaint a variable by thoroughly checking it, e.g. `$number =~m{^(\d+)$} or die; $number = $1;`

Answer (score 4):

From [`perlsec - Taint Mode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode):

> #### Taint Mode
>
> Perl automatically enables a set of special security checks, called *taint mode*, when it detects its program running with differing real and effective user or group IDs. The setuid bit in Unix permissions is mode 04000, the setgid bit mode 02000; either or both may be set. You can also enable taint mode explicitly by using the **-T** command line flag. This flag is *strongly* suggested for server programs and any program run on behalf of someone else, such as a CGI script. Once taint mode is on, it's on for the remainder of your script.
>
> While in this mode, Perl takes special precautions called *taint checks* to prevent both obvious and subtle traps. Some of these checks are reasonably simple, such as verifying that path directories aren't writable by others; careful programmers have always used checks like these. Other checks, however, are best supported by the language itself, and it is these checks especially that contribute to making a set-id Perl program more secure than the corresponding C program.
>
> You may not use data derived from outside your program to affect something else outside your program--at least, not by accident. All command line arguments, environment variables, locale information (see [perllocale](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html)), results of certain system calls ([`readdir()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html), [`readlink()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink.html), the variable of [`shmread()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shmread.html), the messages returned by [`msgrcv()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/msgrcv.html), the password, gcos and shell fields returned by the `getpwxxx()` calls), and all file input are marked as "tainted". Tainted data may not be used directly or indirectly in any command that invokes a sub-shell, nor in any command that modifies files, directories, or processes, ....

Answer (score 1):

Taint is a data that your programs reads from external sources. These data may cause your program to behave differently than it is intended to. Such type of data should be introspected before it is used in the program.